# Package build system for Debian (like Fedora Koji)

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging, deb

I would like to deploy private `deb` package build machine with web interface and Git integration (probably some kind of [Koji](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji)). Does it exist?

If not so, I wonder, how these huge amounts of packages in different branches of Debian and Ubuntu are built? Can't believe that all the workflow is designed on the use of `debuild` via CLI.

Comment: Well, there are tools built around `debuild`, like [`gbp`](https://wiki.debian.org/PackagingWithGit). But what's so unbelievable about a highly-repetitive process being done via CLI and scripting?

Comment: @muru I think that it's hard to control the various problems occurring while packaging when you have only CLI and tonns of logs. Something more complex should lie behind the sites like https://lintian.debian.org/

Comment: Well, `lintian` is a CLI tool, so presumably that site's data is generated by automatically parsing lintian output. I doubt Debian has the man power to hand-curate data like that.

Answer (score 3):

After a month of seeking, I still didn't find suitable build system that could meet the needs of our team. So I had to combine a new one from the existing components. Here they are:

1. [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) (SCM server) Jenkins (CI server and build management tool)
2. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) (light-weighted isolated environment for builds)
3. [Git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.html) (very convenient tool that combines `git` and
   `debuild`; it can create `debian/changelog` from commits, push tags for release)
4. [Aptly](http://www.aptly.info/) (repository for binary Debian packages);
5. Small amount of Python "middleware" code;

However, I learned a lot (thanks to Debian developers) from [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/05/msg00349.html) thread. There are a couple of tools developed by the community that probably can help someone who reading this topic:

1. [jenkins-debian-glue](http://jenkins-debian-glue.org/)
2. [mini-buildd](http://mini-buildd.installiert.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check SUSE Open Build Service (OBS). It supports deb packages builds. Some useful links:

- https://openbuildservice.org/
- https://openbuildservice.org/help/manuals/obs-user-guide/cha.obs.package_formats.html